# Restrict some HTTP Methods on Postman

Tags: postman

I need to restrict some of the HTTP Methods like PUT, POST and DELETE for my one of the environment. Is it possible in POSTMAN ?

This will help me in avoiding mistakes of doing POST,PUT or DELETE on my one of the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a variable to the Method dropdown - Add `{{METHOD}}` to the field and than add the same variable name in your environment file with the value you want?

[image]

You could also just *delete* the Methods you don't want to use from the dropdown, these can just be added in after, if you need it again.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/customizing-postman/#customizing-request-methods

Answer (score 2):

Postman does not provide any in-built functionality like this. However, you can use pre-request scripts for this. Write this in your pre-request script of the API you want to limit certain request methods-

```
var request = pm.request;
if(request.method.includes("POST") || request.method.includes("PUT")){
    console.error("Inavlid request method");
    throw new Error("Invalid request method");
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that you need to copy-paste this in every API's pre-request script. If you want to bypass that, you can cache this entire code into a postman variable and just eval that variable in every API. Steps-

- Create an environment variable in your postman with this name as "my-script" and value as-

> () => {    var request = pm.request;
>   if(request.method.includes("POST") || request.method.includes("PUT")){
>   console.error("Inavlid request method");        throw new
>   Error("Invalid request method");    }}

- Now just copy and paste this line in every pre-request script in your collection-

> eval(pm.environment.get('my-script'))();

Comment: Danny Dainton has a better answer if you want to just restrict HTTP methods. Use my approach when you wanna achieve much more complex stuff, like request validations and or maybe allowing 2 request methods for some requests.

Comment: You could also add this to the Collection or the Folder level pre-request script so it's in a single place :)